# Error in installing matplotlib

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, terminal, installation

I'm installing matplotlib in python on linux.

I used the following command to install.

```
pip install matplotlib
```

It's showing the following error:

```
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pylab.py'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_grayhat/matplotlib/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-YC1nG2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_grayhat/matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
   load_entry_point('pip==1.5.4', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 235, in main
return command.main(cmd_args)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/di`enter code here`st-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: try `sudo pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo pip install matplotlib
```

Your user account doesn't have permission to write to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, but `root` does.